# What is the -W option of GNU getopt() used for?

Tags: c, linux, unix, command-line

Quoted from [the POSIX.1-2008 description about **`-W`** option](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html),

> The **`-W`** (capital-W) option shall be reserved for vendor options.

Quoted from Linux Manual page, [GNU getopt handles **`-W`** option as follows](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getopt.3.html):

> If ***optstring*** contains **W** followed by a <kbd>semicolon</kbd> ( ; ), then **`-W foo`** is treated as the long option **`--foo`**. (The **-W** option is reserved by POSIX.2 for implementation extensions.)

Could someone explain the above sentence in a more clear way (straightforward) and explain why such an option is useful?

The above statement bugs me because I think `getopt` (not `getopt_long`, `getopt_long_only`) only understand short options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out: http://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/api/gnu/getopt/Getopt.html

> Long options can also be specified using a special POSIX argument
>   format (one that I highly discourage). This form of entry is enabled
>   by placing a "W;" (yes, 'W' then a semi-colon) in the valid option
>   string. This causes getopt to treat the name following the "-W" as the
>   name of the long option. For example, "-W outputdir=foo" would be
>   equivalent to "--outputdir=foo". The name can immediately follow the
>   "-W" like so: "-Woutputdir=foo". Option arguments are handled
>   identically to normal long options. If a string follows the "-W" that
>   does not represent a valid long option, then getopt() returns 'W' and
>   the caller must decide what to do. Otherwise getopt() returns a long
>   option value as described below.

Comment: Does gcc flags such as -Wall follow this pattern?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is a bit unclear, my interpretation is that the part about  `-W` only applies to `getopt_long()` and `getopt_long_only()` for that very reason.

Luckily, the GNU C library is open source. :)

Internally, all three of these functions are implemented by calling a worker function (`_getopt_internal()`), and the handling of `-W` is done inside that function. If, however, no long option definitions are available (as will be the case when called from `getopt()`, it will return the `'W'`.

See [this commit](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=01636b2140cd1281202b89f7103249ed598065c4;hp=9895c8bc62759a2d7abf95654fb2aefe5677a930), or just click through to read [posix/getopt.c](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=posix/getopt.c;h=3fa5a4d6d1fd95d5c902d04bf140c750c175c2b5;hb=01636b2140cd1281202b89f7103249ed598065c4) directly.